# Select first child of second level

Tags: css, sass

I need to select the first div with class .tGrid-item within the div .tGrid-row-two but with the :first-child selects me the first t-Grid-item of each .tGrid-row-two

I am using sass

example of code:

```html
<div class="tGrid">
  <div class="tGrid-row-four">
    <div class="tGrid-row-two">
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        this is the one I want to select
      </div>
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        no select
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tGrid-row-two">
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        no select
      </div>
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        no select
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tGrid-row-four">
    <div class="tGrid-row-two">
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        this is the one I want to select
      </div>
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        no select
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tGrid-row-two">
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        no select
      </div>
      <div class="tGrid-item">
        no select
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:first-child` (and the other pseudo-classes) select elements, not classes. Adding a class is like adding a filter on the selector and makes it more restrictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can string together `first-child` selectors like this:

```
.tGrid-row-two:first-child .tGrid-item:first-child { }
```

As @j08691 points out, this will only work if `.tGrid-item` is a direct descendant of `.tGrid-row-two` and there are no siblings preceding it aside from other elements with the `.tGrid-item` class.

```css
.tGrid-row-two:first-child .tGrid-item:first-child {
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tGrid">
 <div class="tGrid-row-four">
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    this is the one I want to select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tGrid-row-four">
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    this is the one I want to select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works if the `<div class="tGrid-item">` is the first child of its parent. The OP wants to select the first `<div class="tGrid-item">` (regardless if it's the first child or not). Add any element before it and you'll see it won't select it.

Comment: The OP never stated that they want to select the first instance of `tGrid-item` _regardless of if it's the first child or not_, this answer is correct based on the HTML they have provided.

Comment: _"I need to select the first div with class .tGrid-item within the div .tGrid-row-two"_

Comment: So where are the words "regardless of if it's the first child or not?"

Comment: Where does he OP state they only want to select it if it's first child? The OP said he *tried* using `:first-child` and it didn't work, not that the div was always the first child.

Comment: Reading the question you can assume what @j08691 points but based on the HTML markup provided with the "no select" and "this select", this answer is valid; maybe make the note to complement the answer that this only will work if ...

Comment: Re-reading the question, that does make sense, added a note for clarity. Although, when the OP says they tried to use first-child and it didn't work, I am assuming that they meant the first child of each instance of `.tGrid-row-two` was being targeted rather than just the first child from the first instance of `.tGrid-row-two` which is what my answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, like this:

```css
.tGrid-row-two:first-child .tGrid-item:first-child {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tGrid">
 <div class="tGrid-row-four">
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    this is the one I want to select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tGrid-row-four">
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    this is the one I want to select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tGrid-row-two">
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
   <div class="tGrid-item">
    no select
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works if the `<div class="tGrid-item">` is the first child of its parent. The OP wants to select the first `<div class="tGrid-item">` (regardless if it's the first child or not). Add any element before it and you'll see it won't select it.

Comment: Doesn't work if I drop other divs in various places. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p80185om/

Comment: @j08691 You're missing a space between `.tGrid-row-two:first-child` and `:first-child:not` in your fiddle